# Understanding definition of flux as a vector field

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow, vector-fields

I'm reading about conservation laws in the book *Mathematical Models in Biology* by Edelstein-Keshet, and I'm a bit confused by the author's definition of flux. For context this is from section 9.3, where the conservation law $\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} \pm \sigma$ is derived. Here, $c = c(\mathbf{x},t)$ denotes the concentration of particles in some domain of space,  $\mathbf{J} = \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x},t)$ is the flux (defined below), and $\pm \sigma$ is the rate at which particles are created/destroyed.

The author's definition of flux (p.397):

> Let us focus attention on a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We shall define *flux* by counting the number of particles per unit time that traverse an imaginary unit area $A$ suspended at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ with some particular orientation. As the orientation of the "test area" is varied, the rate of crossings changes. Indeed, the highest rate of corssings is achieved when the predominant flow direction is orthogonal to the area that it must cross. This leads us to define *flux* as a vector in the direction $\mathbf{n}$ whose magnitude is given by
> $$ |\mathbf{J}(x,y,z,t)| = \text{net number of particles crossing a unit area at } (x,y,z) \text{ per unit time at time } t, $$
>
> where $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit normal vector to that element of area that admits the greatest net crossings.

I'm having a slightly hard time digesting this definition; it just seems rather awkward. Are there any alternative ways of defining flux (e.g. perhaps using a limiting argument that involves mass and velocity)?

Also, a (probably very elementary) question about fluids: Is the velocity field of a "reasonably behaved" fluid assumed to be continuous? I'm curious because it seems to me that defining flux via a limiting argument involving mass and velocity would probably require nearby particles to have approximately the same velocity.

Comment: Can you identify what part of the author's definition you have troubles with? That's seemingly a standard definition (or at least a common one): the number of particles/elements passing through a surface at some time $t$. What more could someone offer?

Comment: $\rho\,d\vec A\cdot \vec v = \rho\,dA\,\hat n\cdot \vec v$ where $\rho$ is the number density, $dA$ the area with unit vector $\hat n$ normal to it and $\vec v$ the velocity.

Comment: And please focus on one question at a time. For your velocity question you could open a separate question. Or do some research first, this is basic material and you are very likely to find resources on this on physics.stackexchange or in your favourite textbooks.

Comment: The flux vector for c is $\mathbf{J}=c\mathbf{v}$.  And v and its derivatives  do have to be assumed continuous.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the equation you mentioned is known as the continuity equation. It's a quite intriguing equation and one of my favorites. Anyway, let's try to understand what the left side of the equation means. To understand this, we have to imagine a system like a box. Inside the box, let's say there are a bunch of electrons, and there is a tunnel from which these electrons can come out of the box, okay? Now, for a moment, let's assume that the number of electrons inside the box is conserved. This means we can't create new electrons, and therefore, **σ** becomes zero (we will come to **σ** later).

Now, let's talk about what **−∇⋅J** means. Before that, let's imagine a simple imaginary shape, like a sphere, that covers the hole of our tunnel. So, **−∇⋅J** essentially tells us how many electrons are passing through the surface of that imaginary sphere. What about the left term in the equation, where **c=c(x,t)** or **c** is nothing but the number of electrons in the box? Because electrons are coming out of the box, the value of **c=c(x,t)** is changing over time,So **∂c/∂t** tells us number of electrons coming out of the box per unite time.

So, this equation basically states that the number of electron leaving the box per unit time is equal to the number of electrons passing through that imaginary sphere or shape that encloses the hole of the tunnel. If you want to learn more about the "continuity equation, you can watch this video:https://youtu.be/eR-LrWfrXl8 (also this ans wasnt taken from openAI i used OpenAI to fix the grammer issues)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).